# Can't get values from Dictionary Property in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties

I have the following code for class called Role

```
public static class Role
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<Permissions>> _userRole;
    private static List<Permissions> _userPermission;

    public static Dictionary<string, List<Permissions>> UserRoleInfo
    {
        get { return _userRole; }
    }

    public Role()
    {
        _userRole = new Dictionary<string, List<Permissions>>();
         _userPermission = new List<Permissions>();
    }}
```

in another class I'm trying to get value of the matching key from the UserRoleInfo Property

```
List<Permissions> value = Role.UserRoleInfo(authenticatedUserName)
```

but i get the following error

```
Error   7   Non-invocable member 'User.Role.UserRoleInfo' cannot be used like a method.
```

any idea how to get around it or where is my mistake, because using

```
if(Role.UserRoleInfo.ContainsKey(authenticatedUserName))
```

works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The right syntax for getting a dictionary value in C# is

   ```
   Role.UserRoleInfo[authenticatedUserName]
   ```
2. Initializing a static member from an instance constructor is a bad idea.  You probably want the constructor to be `static` as well. (or make the fields and property non-static - whichever makes more sense for your usage)

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice I did change it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets to access the members of the dictionary:

```
List<Permissions> value = Role.UserRoleInfo[authenticatedUserName];
```

Comment: @JP.ElRami Make sure you take a look at [@DStanley's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30925905/791010), it covers another important point.